# Change OnClick label color WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im coming from a C# winforms background and I would normally do all this in code.
I have several Labels that I'm using as a menu.
When the mouse hovers over them the text changes color by:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="normalColor" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverColor" Color="Gold" />
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="menuItemStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource normalColor}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource mouseOverColor}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

      <Label x:Name="Label_Video1" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}" Content="1.Video 1."  FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="Label_Video1_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
    <Label x:Name="Label_Video2" Style="{StaticResource menuItemStyle}" Content="2. Video 2." FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="Label_Video2_MouseDown"/>
```

When the user clicks a label I want it to stay a certin color (In this case Gold) and all the others to stay their normal colour. So if a label has been previously clicked and I click another label it will go from gold to white etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using WPF, you have to think slightly differently. We know that the `Label` control doesn't know when it has been clicked and it especially doesn't know when another `Label` element has been clicked... but some controls do. Thinking about it... a `RadioButton` has exactly this behaviour. Now this is where WPF *really* shines.

We can use `RadioButton`s and by providing them with a new `ControlTemplate`, we can make them *look* like plain text:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
x:Type RadioButton}}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold" />
</DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="5" Background="{x:Null}">
        <RadioButton Content="1.Video 1." />
        <RadioButton Content="2.Video 2." />
        <RadioButton Content="3.Video 3." />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If you don't want the `RadioButton`s to be all together in a `StackPanel`, then you can use give them the same `GroupName` property value to ensure that they still operate as one group.

Comment: Thanks this did te trick. But I want to make my text turn gold if its clicked OR the mouse is hovered over it.  Is there a way I can OR together two triggers??

Comment: I got it I just added in the following:        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
                                            </Trigger>

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that other requirement. I've updated my answer accordingly. Please note that you should use the `DataTrigger` that I added which will work with the `RadioButton` and not just the `TextBlock`... you'll see that it works better. You could also add another `DataTrigger` for the `IsPressed` property to highlight when the user is actually clicking on one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one more thing, I have added in code to change the cursor to a hand but when whenever I click the mouse the hand changes back to an arrow. I simply added in <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" /> below where you were setting the Foreground Color. It does change to a hand on mouse over but when I click it changes back.